# Behaviour of debuggers regarding Step Over + Breakpoints

Tags: debugging

(I'm coding a debugger. But my doubt is also from the point of view of a debugger user)

Many debuggers in many languages (GDB, Eclipse) implement a STEP_OVER command that permits to execute one statement at a time; the difference with STEP_INTO is that it does not perform the stepping down in stack (i.e., called functions), which is often a good thing.

```
 10  : y = f1(x);
 11  : z = y + 1;
```

Now, suppose I step over line 10 above, but a breakpoint is hit inside function `f1` (perhaps several levels deep in the call stack). It's not clear what should happen when I resume: should the debugger pause at line 11 (effectively "completing the step over" command)? Or should it forget about it? I believe most (all?) debuggers do the later. Is that the standard/expected behaviour? I myself have found this a little frustrating. Is there a way (in some debugger) to resume execution from the inside breakpoint to the outside stepped-over statement? Or is there some way to do a step-over-ignoring breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

WinDbg does the latter, and I believe this is standard behavior.  If you are worried about a different breakpoint occurring during a step-over command, you could always manually set a breakpoint on line 11 and continue running until line 11 is hit.  Alternatively, you could temporarily disable the other breakpoints, but note that the debugger still may break for other reasons as well (such as raising an exception), depending on its configuration.